# Mobile 3G Connection

Tags: modem, 3g, modem-manager

Hello i'm a newbie Ubuntu user,
I have a Mobile 3G Modem (Vodafone VODEM) , i found my modem's drivers in this [site](http://www.betavine.net/bvportal/resources/datacards/devices) .  I installed it and now i can connect via my 3G Modem very well.

But while i was use Windows, there was an application *(I mean , Vodafone's official modem application, Vodafone Connect)* for my modem. With this application i could send / get SMS , check my bandwidth quota etc.

Are there any application for Linux, like that application ?

1. How can i control my bandwidth quota usage?
2. How can i send / get SMS

Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Vodafone used to offer an application for linux itself, i never used it so i don't know the exact functionality. Right now the site seems to be down for maintenance but you should be able to reach it again in a few hours i guess:
http://www.vodafonebetavine.net/web/linux_drivers

Edit:
Found a link with description and pictures it definitely supports SMS like in Windows:
http://www.howtoforge.com/vodafone_mobile_connect_card_driver_linux

Comment: Thank you i will check. But i think it's just driver and i have driver . I'm writing this comment with my VODEM connection :) Just i need an application for manage this connection and other things (explained in question).

Comment: No definitely also works for SMS edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[Sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/) is one script that supports multiple carriers across multiple countries. Just download the sakis3g script and install it. You'll have to work with it for few minutes to get the connection running. Once you get it connected you can create desktop shortcut and run it next time. I did the same on ubuntu 10.10.